# No win7 option in grub boot loader screen

Tags: grub2, windows-7

I had win7 installed.  I then upgraded to win10 via a fresh install. No problems. A couple of time loading windows, I had to go thru what I think was a windows7 loader (dos looking) and the next time it might be thru what must be a win10 loader...more graphical.
Then, I went and installed Ubuntu 18.04 as my choice for a linux distro.
Now when I boot, I get the grub loader, but it only lists Ubuntu and windows10. No windows7.  I tried running the os prober from Ubuntu, but it still did not detect win7 as a boot choice. I can still get into win7 via the windows10 menu entry in grub. That menu entry takes me to the windows boot loader, and then on into whichever OS I choose.. 10 or 7, which are both listed. No Ubuntu option in the windows boot loader. I can get into Ubuntu simply by choosing it at the grub loader screen.
I ran boot repair.  Here is the url of the results.
http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/ChvQb5sK34/
Thanks in advance.
Ed.

Comment: Both Windows 7 and Windows 10 use the same Windows bootloader, which is why there is no separate listings in grub.

Comment: Well Mikewhatever, you would have to see it to believe it then, but I have dual and triple booted in the past, and all menuentries for all three operating systems, including the linux partition, were offered in the grub loader at startup time. I have had issues where, when windows was installed after Linux, the windows bootloader would take over, very possessive, lol
This time, when I installed windows10, after 7,  windows 10, I believe, took over the dual boot with its graphical like bootup screen,  listing both 7 and 10, but next boot experience would be different...

Comment: ....Sometimes on bootup, I get a black screen with white text only, and 7 & 10 listed. Sometimes it was a blue graphical like screen, with 7 & 10 listed. (I figured 10s bootloader).  Then after Ubuntu was installed, grub stole the whole show...no problem, cept that 7 is not listed. And like I said, if I choose to boot 10, it goes to it's bootloader next, where 7&10 are both listed. If I chcoose from there to go into 10 it does so right away. If I choose 7, it auto reboots and, grub pops up,  I choose 10 again, and it boots right into 7.  I need2 know  how2 add 7 to the grub screen successfully

Comment: Im not experienced nuff 2  look at the bootrepair output, and know what lines to add to grub cfg.  I have tried a few different entries in grub cfg, but they didn't work out. Things are the same. So if someone can look at my repair output log above, maybe ya can figure out what lines I need to add to grub. 
Thanks